# Weblogic 10.3.6 Ignores @HandlerChain

Tags: web-services, weblogic, jax-ws

I've created a simple EJB3 WebService , that supposed to be intercepted by a SOAPHandler.
 I get no errors\warnings during the build (I used to get classpath errors , they're all fixed) , and I'm able to deploy and invoke the WS , but the server completely ignores the HandlerChain part , and it's never gets hit.
My code  is :
 
The Handler  :

```
public   class SecuritySOAPHandler implements SOAPHandler<SOAPMessageContext> { ... }
```

The Bean :

```
@Stateless
@WebService(
        portName = "ExampleWSPort",
        serviceName="ExampleWS"     
        )
@HandlerChain( file="handlerchain.xml")
public class ExampleWS {

    public ExampleWS()
    {

    }
    @WebMethod
 public String first(String input)
 {
     return input + " Got";
 }
```

handlerchain.xml :

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<jws:handler-chains xmlns:jws="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee">
<!-- Note:  The '*" denotes a wildcard. -->

    <jws:handler-chain name="MyHandlerChain">
        <jws:protocol-bindings>##SOAP11_HTTP ##ANOTHER_BINDING</jws:protocol-bindings>
        <jws:port-name-pattern 
              xmlns:ns1="http://handlersample.samples.ibm.com/">ns1:MySampl*</jws:port-name-pattern>
        <jws:service-name-pattern 
              xmlns:ns1="http://handlersample.samples.ibm.com/">ns1:*</jws:service-name-pattern>
        <jws:handler>
            <jws:handler-class>com.soaphandlers.SecuritySOAPHandler</jws:handler-class>
        </jws:handler>

    </jws:handler-chain>

</jws:handler-chains>
```

Any help appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: Where's your implementation of your handler?

Comment: I assume it is only 
return true; (and null for getHeaders() ) of
SOAPHandler<SOAPMessageContext> interface methods.

Answer (score 1):

I was having similar issues and found the following:

- Apparently the absolute or class path does not work very well, so either put the xml in the same folder as the ExampleWS class or use ../, for instance, in my case I have it like this:

  `@HandlerChain(file="../../../../../../../META-INF/ws-handler-config.xml")`
- The jws: namespace that comes from the examples was giving also problems so I just made it simple:

  `<handler-chains xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee">

         <handler-chain>

           <handler>

           <handler-class>util.interceptors.SOAPLoggingHandler</handler-class>

        </handler>

     </handler-chain>

  </handler-chains>`

With this changes, it works!